# Change the Value of Column When Condition is met

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I need help to make a query that groups up dates, and then, tell me if in those dates there are Dates with one or more diferent colors and change the value of the column color for those dates:

```
// What I have
    DATE    |  Color  
 23/01/2019 |  BLUE      
 24/01/2019 |  RED       
 24/01/2019 |  RED
 24/01/2019 |  RED
 27/01/2019 |  RED
 27/01/2019 |  GREEN
 28/01/2019 |  PURPLE
 29/01/2019 |  YELLOW
 02/02/2019 |  BROWN
 02/02/2019 |  BLUE
 15/02/2019 |  RED
 17/02/2019 |  RED
 17/02/2019 |  PURPLE
 20/02/2019 |  WHITE
 23/02/2019 |  BLACK
 27/02/2019 |  CYAN


// Output I need
    DATE    |  Color  
 23/01/2019 |  BLUE      
 24/01/2019 |  RED
 27/01/2019 |  MULTIPLE
 28/01/2019 |  PURPLE
 29/01/2019 |  YELLOW
 02/02/2019 |  MULTIPLE
 15/02/2019 |  RED
 17/02/2019 |  MULTIPLE
 20/02/2019 |  WHITE
 23/02/2019 |  BLACK
 27/02/2019 |  CYAN
```

I made a query that groups up the dates and tells me **how many** colors there is in each event, but not **how many different**

The query I made is:

```
SELECT Date, color, COUNT(*) AS ColorCount 
FROM Events 
GROUP BY DataDoc 
HAVING ColorCount > 0
```

I need this for a calendar app I'm making, and Im using SQLite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go for this:

```
select date, case when count(distinct color) >1 then 'MULTIPLE' else color end as color
from events
group by date
```

EDIT:
Remember to add DISTINCT or a day with same color multiple times will be counted multiple times

Comment: I think this was exactly what I wanted, I didn't even know that was possible, thank you very much, you just saved my life!

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation and `case`:

```
SELECT Date,
       (CASE WHEN MIN(color) = MAX(color) THEN MIN(color)
             ELSE 'MULTIPLE'
         END)
FROM Events
GROUP BY Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain this is all you want to know:

> but not how many different

You can solve this with the "distinct" parameter, like this>:

SELECT DATE, count(DISTINCT COLOR) CountColors FROM `list1` group by DATE

According to the manual, this should work on SQLite.